# My lambda python doesn't get all results from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Very strange my Lambda function does not bring all results from DynamoDB. I found it strange because using the AWS console it returns 10 results and the Lambda function returns nothing. I created an index to see if it was a performance problem, but the error persists.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import os
import time
import csv
import botocore.config as boto_config
import botocore
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key,Attr
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests


#Realiza a leitura dos registros no dynamo do dia anterior
def get_dynamo_daily_data():
    print("Buscando dados no Dynamo")
    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', config=boto_config.Config(max_pool_connections=100)).Table(os.environ["TABLE"])
    
    geocodes = []
 
    #Buscamos os registros do dia anterior
    scan_kwargs = {
        'IndexName': 'created-index',
         'FilterExpression': 'created = :pk',
         'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
            ':pk': get_yesterday_date()
          },
          
         'ProjectionExpression': 'created'

       # 'FilterExpression': Key('created').eq(get_yesterday_date())
    }

    response = dynamodb.scan(**scan_kwargs)
   # response = dynamodb.scan(FilterExpression=Attr("created").eq(get_yesterday_date()))
    
    print(response)

    for i in response['Items']:
        geocodes.append(i)

    print("Retornando dados do Dynamo, registros: {}".format(len(geocodes)))

    return geocodes

#Retorna o dia anterior
def get_yesterday_date():
    today = datetime.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=21)


    return yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    #Cria o arquivo para atualização do pelias
def create_csv_daily_file():
    
    path ='geocoder/data/csv_files/'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    print("Iniciando função para leitura e gravação dos dados")
    data = get_dynamo_daily_data()

    print("Criando arquivo no modelo aceito pelo pelias")
    #Gravamos em um arquivo CSV
    with open('/tmp/' + get_yesterday_date() + ".csv", mode= "w") as op:
        daily_data_csv = csv.writer(op, delimiter= ",")

        line = ["id", "source", "layer", "housenumber", "street", "postalcode", "lat", "lon", "name", "neighbourhood", "city", "state"]
        daily_data_csv.writerow(line)
        
        for x, i in enumerate(data):
            street = i['street'].replace(",", " ")
            name = "{} {}".format(street, i['street_number'])
            line = [x,
                i["origin"],
                "address",
                i["street_number"],
                street,
                i["postal_code"],
                i["latitude"],
                i["longitude"],
                name,
                i["neighborhood"],
                i["city"],
                i["state"]]
                
            daily_data_csv.writerow(line)

    print("Finalizando processo de criação de arquivo: " + get_yesterday_date() + ".csv")
    
    s3.upload_file('/tmp/' + get_yesterday_date() + ".csv", os.environ["BKP"], path + get_yesterday_date() + ".csv")

    return daily_data_csv
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Iniciando processo de atualização do BD do pelias")
    #Criamos o arquivo
    csv_daily_file = create_csv_daily_file()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

I expected it to return all records on that date but it returns none.

Comment: Remove the FilterExpression and ProjectionExpression and tell me if you get data.

Comment: Dont working... because, the 
index expects parameters .

Comment: An index does not expect parameters for a Scan other than `TableName` and `IndexName`. `TableName` you failed to use

Answer (score 0):

Try your request like this, be sure to add a valid table name:

```
   scan_kwargs = {
        'TableName': 'my-table-name',
        'IndexName': 'created-index'
    }

    response = dynamodb.scan(**scan_kwargs)
```